# Read input from StdIn when redirecting StdIn to python manage.py shell

Tags: python, django, shell, stdin

I have a python script that I call redirecting it to Django `manage.py shell`.

```
$ python manage.py shell < script.py
```

I want to take an answer from user to decide what to do. But I can't do it neither with `input()` or `sys.stdin.readline()`.

**With input()**

```
answer = input('A question')
if answer == 'y':
    # Do something
else:
    pass
```

Error:

```
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

**With sys.stdin.readline:**

```
answer = sys.stdin.readline()
if answer == 'y':
    # Do something
else:
    pass
```

In this case script continues without wait for user input.

What's the correct way for doing that?

Comment: Why are you passing the string "A question" to readline()?

Comment: Sorry, I've corrected question.

Comment: Have you tried it it with raw_input() instead of input()?

Comment: `raw_input` was renamed to `input` in Python 3.

Comment: I think the issue is related from trying to get input from `stdin`, when already in a `stdin` stream redirection. Cause both commands appears to be considering `stdin` the next file character.

Answer (score 2):

You're making `./manage.py shell` get some input, but the input you've provided was the contents of `script.py`.

It would be a lot nicer to write a custom [Django management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-management-commands/). For example:

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand

class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        answer = input('A question')
        if answer == 'y':
            # Do something
        else:
            pass
```

which you would then call with `manage.py my_script`.